# Umbraco - The Xml cache is corrupt. Use the Health Check data integrity dashboard to fix it

Tags: umbraco, web-deployment, umbraco7

I am getting this error after deploying Umbraco website to the shared hosting site.

Couldn't able to find any solution. Tried refreshing `App Pool`

> The Xml cache is corrupt. Use the Health Check data integrity dashboard to fix it.

[image]

Please if anyone can help, I am on production server now. Local is running perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

We've had the same issue recur a few times over the last few weeks, with content editors suddenly unable to preview anything.

- "Republish entire site" - doesn't work
- Restarting the site / recycle app pool - doesn't work
- Deleting Umbraco's cache - doesn't work
- umbracoUseSSL is already set correctly

What does work, every time: *Empty Umbraco's recycle bin!*

Can anyone provide some insight as to why that's a solution, or anything we can do about it? How could the recycle bin's contents even be involved in the previewing functionality?

---

*Edit: the issue we were experiencing was fixed in the 7.15.1 update, as mentioned by Steve Megson [here](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/99087-recurring-xml-cache-is-corrupt-issues):*

> *There was an issue with preview in 7.15.0 (fixed in 7.15.1) which
>   would throw this exception when it failed to generate the preview
>   version of the XML cache*

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to access the URL "/umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true" on your production server?

I've had this happen in the past on earlier versions of Umbraco, and after running this I have been able to go into the backoffice and address the issues with the XML data integrity.

Outside of this, I echo Robert's point on posting on Our.

Comment: If you were to use a backup of the production site on your local code base, does it work?

Comment: To indulge me, have you tried clearing all the runtime generated files from your App_Data folder? Things like your Examine indexes and the like.

Answer (score 1):

See this [forum thread on our.umbraco.org](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/85834-the-xml-cache-is-corrupt-use-the-health-check-data-integrity-dashboard-to-fix-it)

It provides some troubleshooting tips you can try.  It would also help to know what version of Umbraco the site is running on.

Comment: Nothing works sir, that's why I posted here. Can you guide me?

Comment: first of all, what version of Umbraco is the site running on?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Umbraco version 7.9.2, App pool restarted, tried deleting Umbraco.config file

Comment: Post the question on the forum on Our.Umbraco - I'll make sure it's not marked as spam, and you'll be able to get the help of the full Umbraco community - there are too many variables to be able to answer it here

Comment: Something else you can try is looking in the logfile in ~/App_Data/Logs and see if there are any exceptions thrown there.  It's possible there's a specific content node that's failing to publish properly, and you may need to go directly to it and click the Publish button.

Answer (score 1):

The same error message also appears if you forget to add `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` to the connection string!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, i have fixed this by editing the web.config file.
I had to set `umbracoUseSSL` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

The web.config setting `<add key="Umbraco.Preview.Mode" value="Legacy" />` is fixing it for us in version 7.15.6

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after upgrading an old v4 website to the latest version of v7(7.15.10) and adding MaxPool=1000 to the connection string seems to have fixed the problem.